# Imacros.... start a new line in a data extraction CSV file

Tags: newline, imacros

I currently have the following macro:

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/chocolate_and_orange_87739
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:article-title EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ingredients EXTRACT=TXT
ADD INTERNAL {{#NEWLINE#}}
URL GOTO=http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/secret_squirrel_cake_49338
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:article-title EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ingredients EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Data_Extract_BBC FILE=Ollytest1.csv
```

I want this to write to a new line for each URL I hit, but in the file it puts them both on the same line. Is there a command to start new line?

That's the main question. My other question is... how can I get Imacro's to crawl the whole of the site and take the recepies off every page where they exist? Some pages may not have recepies on. I cant find a list on the sitemap of the URL's and the URL's are not just numbers. How can I make Imacros explore links on the site?

Comment: saveas will save data to new line anyway - just add id after each extract you want to save - it also should clear value in !extract after save

Comment: For your second question go to this page http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes#quick-recipe-finder and check all national cuisines from the bottom section. Than make a Imacros script to extract all 15 links from one page and click the Next button. To execute it use the Play Loop button.

Answer (score 4):

To start a new line you can do this:

```
ADD !VAR1 <BR>
```

Answer (score 3):

code example

```
VERSION BUILD=9002379
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/chocolate_and_orange_87739
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:article-title EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ingredients EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Data_Extract_BBC FILE=Ollytest1.csv
set !extract null
URL GOTO=http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/secret_squirrel_cake_49338
ADD !EXTRACT {{!URLCURRENT}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:article-title EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ingredients EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\Data_Extract_BBC FILE=Ollytest1.csv
```